# What is the exact order of initializing jQuery functions?

Tags: jquery

I have a question related to order of applying functions in jQuery (It's a little different than the other questions I found on stackoverflow).

I have a function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loading();
});

function loading() {
// some code
$('.button1').click(function(){
function(first);
});
$('.button2').click(function(){
function(second);
});
$('.button3').click(function(){
function(third);
});

function (first) {
// code to execute 1
}
function (second) {
// code to execute 2
}
function (third) {
// code to execute 3
}
```

My problem is, only code from *function(third)* is being executed and no matter which button I click. So I need to put every *code to execute* into *function(third)* to have it working. I wanted to make actions a little bit different depending on which button is being clicked, and I don't know why it doesnt't work in order I presented above. maybe someone could help me?

### EDIT

That's the whole function I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loading();
});

function loading() {
    if (typeof history.pushState !== "undefined") {
        var historyCount = 0;
        $('.button').click(function(){
            var getlink = $(this).attr('href');
            goTo(getlink);
            history.pushState(null, null, getlink);
            return false;
        });
        $('.projects').click(function(){
            var projects = $(this).attr('href');
            goTo(projects);
            history.pushState(null, null, projects);
            return false;
        });
        $('.home').click(function(){
            var homepage = $(this).attr('href');
            goTo(homepage);
            history.pushState(null, null, homepage);
            return false;
        });
    }
}
function goTo(homepage) {
    $.ajax({url: homepage, success: function(data) {
        $('.container_right_wrapper').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 200, function(){
        $(this).html(data).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 200);
        $( ".pageicon img" ).remove();
        var image = $('.container_right_wrapper .img').prop('src');
        $('.pageicon').append('<img src="'+image+'"/>');
        });
    }
    });
}
function goTo(projects) {
    $.ajax({url: projects,success: function(data) {
        $('.container_right_wrapper').hide('slide', {direction: 'left',easing:'linear'}, 200, function(){
        $(this).html(data).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 200);
            carousel();
        $( ".pageicon img" ).remove();
        var image = $('.container_right_wrapper .img').prop('src') ;
        $('.pageicon').append('<img src="'+image+'"/>');
        });
    }
    });
}
function goTo(getlink) {
    $.ajax({url: getlink,success: function(data) {
        $('.container_right_wrapper').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 300, function(){
        $(this).html(data).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 300);
            slider();
        $( ".pageicon img" ).remove();
        var image = $('.container_right_wrapper .img').prop('src') ;
        $('.pageicon').append('<img src="'+image+'"/>');
        });
    }
    });
}
```

so again: When I click on .projects I'd like to have carousel(); plug-in executed,but it doesn't work. I need to put it in the last function along with slider(); to make it work, and I don't know why? Sorry guys, I made a mistake in my first example, that caused a little havoc...

Comment: How is that syntax even working?

Comment: Well, it's working but not in the way I expect. I just wanted to omit writing three different functions for three sifferent button click events.

Comment: Your `function` statements look all messed up.

Comment: What you posted is full of syntax errors, so whatever *is* working is not this code.

Comment: Ok, I'll post a whole function, but I wanted to make it shorter, as for me it looks exactly the same in terms of order they appear in the script tag..

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gHGBw/1/ - not working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gHGBw/2/ - working

Comment: With `function (first)` are you trying to define a function named first or waiting for a variable named first? If 1st one, you need `function first()`, in 2nd you need `function A_NAME_FOR_FUNCTION(first)`

Comment: Sorry, My bad, I made a mistake, I't better to post the whole function...

Comment: You have three functions with the same name. You can't do that; the next one will always overwrite the previous. I suggest you read up on how function parameters work.

Comment: so function goTo(projects) is the same as function goTo(getlink)? How should I name it to make it differ form each other?

Comment: I tried to change `function goTo(projects)` to `function second()` and call it not as `goTo(projects);` but as `second();` I repeated the process to other two functions (giving them adequate names)...it stopped to work completely...

Comment: Nevermind, I got rid of three separate functions and pasted their code in place of `goTo(projects);` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you've defined your function in the wrong way, you can do like this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // some code
    $('.button1').click(function () {
        first();
    });
    $('.button2').click(function () {
        second();
    });
    $('.button3').click(function () {
        third();
    });

    function first() {
        // code to execute 1
    }

    function second() {
        // code to execute 2
    }

    function third() {
        // code to execute 3
    }

});
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, I wanted to make an example funtion as a shorthand but I made a mistake in syntax..